# Difficulties getting automated posts to work properly

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my web app I have the following facebook-related code being executed when a user submits a page in my application:

```
<SCRIPT>
function SCRIPTRUN3() {
 FB.login(function(response){
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    var workedOK = 'YES';
     });
    if (workedOK != 'YES') {
        SCRIPTRUN4();
        var workedOK = 'NO';
    };
    SCRIPTRUN5();
   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
};
   }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
</SCRIPT>
```

which calls:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function SCRIPTRUN5() {
   var body = "<Computed Value>";
   FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured: ' + response.error.message);
   } else {
     alert('An announcement was successfully posted to your Facebook wall.');
   }
 });
}
</SCRIPT>
```

When the code execute I get the following error message:

"Error occured: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Followed by:
"An announcement was successfully posted to your Facebook wall."

Am I executing incorrect code? Too much code? Not enough code? I am trying to post an announcement to the user's facebook wall when they post a document on my site.

Any help would be much appreciated. I am really in the dark with this facebook coding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass access_token parameter when calling FB.api, you can find it in authResponse object.